# Laying Out UIView Subviews with Size Constraints

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Given a view hierarchy that looks something like this:

```
ContainerView
  UIScrollView
    ModuleView
    ModuleView
    ModuleView
    ...
```

I'd like the `ContainerView` to lay the `ModuleViews` out in some arbitrary fashion (list, grid etc.). To do this, I'd implement `-[ContainerView layoutSubviews]` which would iterate through the `ModuleViews`, call `-[ModuleView sizeToFit]` on each one, and then position them relative to one another according to the desired layout.

My question is to do with the best way of implementing `-[ModuleView sizeThatFits:]` and `-[ModuleView layoutSubviews]` to minimise repetition and to allow `ModuleViews` to change size while maintaining the layout correctly.

Take the simplest case where `ModuleView` is a `UIView` with a multi-line `UILabel` subview, and padding on either side. It might look something like this:

```
@implementation ModuleView

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
  CGFloat padding = 10.0f;
  CGSize labelMaxSize = CGSizeMake(superview.size.width - (2 * padding), CGFLOAT_MAX);
  CGSize labelSize = [self.label.text sizeWithFont:self.label.font constrainedToSize:labelMaxSize lineBreakMode:self.label.lineBreakMode];
  return CGSizeMake(superview.width, labelSize.height + (2 * padding));
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];

  CGFloat padding = 10.0f;
  CGSize labelMaxSize = CGSizeMake(self.size.width - (2 * padding), CGFLOAT_MAX);
  CGSize labelSize = [self.label.text sizeWithFont:self.label.font constrainedToSize:labelMaxSize lineBreakMode:self.label.lineBreakMode];
  self.label.frame = CGRectMake(padding, padding, labelSize.width, labelSize.height);

  CGRect frame = self.frame;
  frame.size.height = self.label.frame.size.height + (2 * padding);
  self.frame = frame;
}

@end
```

As you can see, the size of the subviews is calculated once in `sizeThatFits:`, and again in `layoutSubviews`. This works, but quickly becomes a mess when the views are more complicated.

Is there a way to simplify this? I haven't been able to find good examples of how others approach this problem.

Comment: Hi Nathan, any new solution for such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

I've come in the same kind of problem, with really complex views hierarchy. I ended up by creating a UIView subclass which only **acts as wrappers containing my *useful* views**.

Because I needed to call -(void)sizeToFit from the top of the hierarchy I need a way to apply this *sizing* from bottom to top. I made this by calling -(void)sizeToFit; on subviews right from the superview's -(CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size; method.

And then this is done recursively.

I was so stuck at how to achieve this in the right order that I wrote a note to myself and hopefully others. Hope this can help: http://jchatard.com/understanding-uiview-layout-mecanism